# Condition check in where clause in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I am struggling for a query that allows me to check for a specific date (greater that and less than in 2 different condition). Now my query is like this

```
WHERE lastupdatedon < (
CASE
WHEN
  (
         SELECT count(*)
         FROM   mytable) > 0 THEN
  (
         SELECT max(date)
         FROM   mytable)
  ELSE getdate()
END)
```

But I need to consider that `'>'` also in the condition check, i.e

- If there are no elements in `MyTable` then condition should be `LastUpdatedOn < GETDATE()`
- If there are elements in `MyTable` then condition should be `LastUpdatedOn > Max(Date) from MyTable`

Comment: So what isn't working for what you have?

Comment: Don't jump to `CASE` expressions when what you want to express can just be done using simple conditions and `AND`s and `OR`s.

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume that updated dates are never in the future.  If that is the case, then you might consider:

```
WHERE lastupdatedon > ISNULL( (SELECT MAX(date) FROM mytable), '2000-01-01')
```

Note:  Although I generally prefer `COALESCE()`, `ISNULL()` is (sadly) more efficient in SQL Server with subqueries.

That is, use `>` and a date far in the past.  Of course, this logic is not exactly the same, because `date` could be `NULL` in the table.

An alternative is:

```
WHERE (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytable) AND
       lastupdatedon < GETDATE()
      ) OR
      lastupdatedon > (SELECT MAX(date) FROM mytable);
```

Comment: `ISNULL` not `IFNULL`